Equivalent definition of mutual independence of events
My probability textbook says that
"A collection of events $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1,\dots,A_m \}$ are mutually independent if for any subset of $\mathcal{A}$, $A_{i_1}, \dots, A_{i_k}$, for $k \leq n$, we have $$P(A_{i_1} \cap \dots \cap A_{i_k}) = P(A_{i_1}) \cdots P(A_{i_k}).$$
I was trying to make sense of this definition and motivate it somehow, and came up with the following.
It seems to me, that intuitively, mutual independence should mean that the knowledge that some events from $\mathcal{A}$ occurred shouldn't influence the probability of some other events from $\mathcal{A}$.
More concretely, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint nonempty subsets of $\mathcal{A}$, we should have that
$$
P\left( \bigcap \alpha \right) 
= P\left(\bigcap \alpha  \mathrel{\bigg|} \bigcap \beta \right).
$$
Since
$$
P\left(\bigcap \alpha  \mathrel{\bigg|} \bigcap \beta \right) = \frac{P\left(\bigcap (\alpha \cup \beta)\right)}{P\left(\bigcap \beta \right)},
$$
this condition is equivalent to
$$
P\left(\bigcap (\alpha \cup \beta)\right) = P\left( \bigcap \alpha \right) P\left(\bigcap \beta \right) \text{       }(*).
$$
I tried to prove equivalence in the following way.
First, assume that $(*)$ holds.
Let $S \subseteq \mathcal{A}$; let $\alpha_1 = \{ A_1 \}$ for $A_1 \in S$, and let $\beta_1 = S - \alpha_1$. Then
$$P\left( \bigcap S \right)
= P\left( \bigcap(\alpha_1 \cup \beta_1) \right)
= P\left(\bigcap \alpha_1\right)P\left(\bigcap \beta_1\right)
= P(A_1) P\left( \bigcap(S - \alpha_1) \right).
$$
Now let $\alpha_2 = \{A_2\}$ for $A_2 \in S - \alpha_1$ and let $\beta_2 = \beta_1 - \alpha_2$, then
$$P\left(\bigcap(S - \alpha_1)\right) = P\left( \bigcap(S - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2) \right)P(A_2),$$
etc until we're left with the product $\prod_{A \in S} P(A)$.
Assuming that the textbook definition holds, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be disjoint, nonempty subsets of $\mathcal{A}$. Then,
$$
P\left( \bigcap (\alpha \cup \beta) \right)
= \prod_{A \in \alpha \cup \beta}P(A)
= \left(\prod_{A \in \alpha}P(A)\right)\left(\prod_{B \in \beta}P(B)\right)
= P\left( \bigcap \alpha \right)P\left( \bigcap \beta\right).
$$
Is my reasoning correct?

People prefer your textbook's approach because the other has a denominator. That is, conditioning on events with probability $0$ is very problematic and should be avoided when possible.  As you remark, if you exclude cases with $0$ probability, the definitions are equivalent.

Maybe I didn't phrase my question well, but my end goal was proving that the condition marked with (*) is equivalent to the textbook definition, and I would like to know if that is indeed the case and if my proof is correct

Not following the notation.  What is the intersection of $\alpha \cup \beta$?

It's the intersection of events in $\alpha \cup \beta$. Apologies if the notation is confusing.

I suggest:  Just take two events, $A,B$.  What is your proposed definition for their independence?  Usually people prefer $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ but it's more intuitive (I feel) to write $P(A,|,B)=P(A)$ if you ignore $P(B)=0$ cases.   Is yours the same as one or the other of these?

The (*) statement in this case: The only choice here is $\alpha={A}$, $\beta={B}$, so P(intersection of sets in $\alpha \cup \beta$) is $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

Ok...so how does your definition differ from your textbook's?  What's the simplest case in which they are not exactly the same?

I hope it doesn't differ. I want to know if (*) is equivalent to the textbook definition, that's what I tried to show here.

Other than the notation, I don't see any difference.
